# How to map JavaScript code to Google v8?

Tags: javascript, v8

I mean, in JavaScript, there is string operation, how to find Google v8 code process string operation? How to find Google v8 code process array related operation? how to find Google v8 code process prototype related operation?

Is there any guide about how to read google v8 source code? I want to hook some Javascript operations in google v8.

Thanks, any hint is highly appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a guide (not guild) how to manage V8s source code? I'm afraid you'll just have to check it out and load it in an IDE to help you navigate it.

Comment: @Mjh, thanks for pointing out my typo. The code is huge, if there is any clue, it is great.

Comment: Have you gone through the [guide on google pages](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started)?

Comment: @Mjh, yes, I successfully run the hello world program. But I want to hook some JavaScript operations in v8. For example, if there is assignment operation on array element, I want to output some logs. So I need to find out Google v8 code which cope with Javascript array.

Comment: @wildpointercs it's a lot of code spread across dozens of files and implemented in a mixture of C++ and aseembly, `a[i] = 0` can be handled by multiple code paths in runtime, inline cache stubs/handlers, and optimizing compilers. there is no single simple place you can change [though if you disable optimizing compiler and inline caches - then you will only need to hook into stuff in runtime]

Answer (score 0):

[V8 Engine](https://code.google.com/p/v8/)

Here you can find everything - documentation and instructions.

You have to read up on it, there is no easy way.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [google's V8 code here](https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/Source). 
If you want to see V8 code at runtime, you can't.

For instance: the [IndexOf method](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/runtime/runtime-strings.cc#132) for [String](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/runtime/runtime-strings.cc#132) is:

```
RUNTIME_FUNCTION(Runtime_StringIndexOf) {
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  DCHECK(args.length() == 3);

  CONVERT_ARG_HANDLE_CHECKED(String, sub, 0);
  CONVERT_ARG_HANDLE_CHECKED(String, pat, 1);
  CONVERT_ARG_HANDLE_CHECKED(Object, index, 2);

  uint32_t start_index;
  if (!index->ToArrayIndex(&start_index)) return Smi::FromInt(-1);

  RUNTIME_ASSERT(start_index <= static_cast<uint32_t>(sub->length()));
  int position = StringMatch(isolate, sub, pat, start_index);
  return Smi::FromInt(position);
}
```